# How to extract attachment inside file imap

Tags: imap

I have a file .imap, if I open it using notepad I can see that it is an email with an attachment which is a pdf file. I wish to extract such pdf, how can i perform this operation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about opening that file with an email client instead of a simple text editor?

Comment: Rename it to file.eml, open it with an email client, such as thunderbird or outlook.

Comment: thanks, this works for me.